# How do I change position of a "fixed" element/header to go below Admin toolbar when in Admin view?

Tags: commerce, javascript, theming

*New to JS / CSS*

How do I change / control the position of a sticky navigation bar to go below Admin toolbar when in Admin mode?

Site uses:

1. Subtheme of Omega / Commerce Kickstart
2. Through subtheming, I have two sticky "zones": (1) user (contains login/checkout); (2) menu-super (main menu)
3. User zone is sticky and came as part of the Commerce Kickstart theme and works in both regular user and admin mode.
4. My new "Menu-Super" works in regular user mode, but disappears behind the admin toolbar when viewing as an admin. (less than ideal.)

In the js file, I found the following:

`// Handle user toolbar when user is admin and have admin toolbar enabled.
  Drupal.behaviors.commerce_kickstart_theme_custom_toolbar = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      if ($('body').hasClass('toolbar')) {
        $(window, context).resize(function() {
          var toolbarHeight = $('div#toolbar').height();
          $('.zone-user-wrapper').css('top', toolbarHeight + 'px');
        });
      }
    }
  }`

I tried repurposing this code to handle my new zone, but no dice. When I clear cache, I can see the zone built and then pop up under the admin bar. What am I missing here?

`Drupal.behaviors.commerce_kickstart_theme_custom_toolbar = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      if ($('body').hasClass('toolbar')) {
        $(window, context).resize(function() {
          var toolbarHeight = $('div#toolbar').height();
          var zoneuserHeight = $('div#toolbar').height()+ $('div#zone-user').height();
          $('.zone-menu-super-wrapper').css('top', zoneuserHeight + 'px');
        });
      }
    }
  }`

where the css file specifies

User Zone (Working)

`.zone-user-wrapper {
  background-color: #666666;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%; }`

Super Menu Zone (Not working)

`.zone-menu-super-wrapper {
  background-color: #9E4934; /*Monkey brown*/
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%; 
  position: fixed;
  top: 32px;
  z-index: 99;}`

Comment: Are you using the contrib admin_menu or the normal admin toolbar from Drupal 7? This can be fixed with CSS but the answer depends on which one you are actually using

Comment: @burnsjeremy: I am using the admin menu that comes with Commerce Kickstart. It is a customized menu that comes as part of that distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**In drupal you need to use jquery like this**

```
(function ($) {
 $( document ).ready(function() {

      // custom code here

     });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

**So try**:

```
(function ($) {
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      Drupal.behaviors.commerce_kickstart_theme_custom_toolbar = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
          if ($('body').hasClass('toolbar')) {
            $(window, context).resize(function() {
              var toolbarHeight = $('div#toolbar').height();
              $('.zone-user-wrapper').css('top', toolbarHeight + 'px');
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

If that doesn't work, all you have to do is check if the toolbar div class or id exists.

```
if ($('#toolbar').length > 0) {
    // dostuff
}
```

So if there is a wrapper that wraps everything on your site **except** the admin toolbar. that would be more ideal to use. So all you do is move everything down by 10 or so pixels

[Using CSS with jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

```
(function ($) {
 $( document ).ready(function() {
          if ($('#toolbar').length > 0) {
           $('.zone-user-wrapper').css({"position": "relative", "top": "10px"})
           }
     });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to point me in the right direction. Please let me clarify.

Comment: The new js I added is within the function callout with the other code that came with Kickstart. The js code that I provided for 'zone-user-wrapper' works. I created a second zone / region ("menu-super") that sits below the "user" zone and want it to be handled in the same way. When I try to add identical code for the second zone, nothing happens.

Comment: highlight the second zone / region and right mouse click and select inspect element. double check that the div wrapper is indeed `.zone-menu-super-wrapper` perhaps you have the wrong name?

Answer (score 0):

> The new js I added is within the function callout with the other code
>   that came with Kickstart. The js code that I provided for
>   'zone-user-wrapper' works. I created a second zone / region
>   ("menu-super") that sits below the "user" zone and want it to be
>   handled in the same way. When I try to add identical code for the
>   second zone, nothing happens.

highlight the second zone / region and right mouse click and select inspect element. double check that the div wrapper is indeed `.zone-menu-super-wrapper` perhaps you have the wrong name?

**you don't need 2 separate codes** just add the

```
var zoneuserHeight = $('div#toolbar').height()+ $('div#zone-user').height();
```

and

```
 $('.zone-menu-super-wrapper').css('top', zoneuserHeight + 'px');
```

lines to your first code

```
   Drupal.behaviors.commerce_kickstart_theme_custom_toolbar = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
          if ($('body').hasClass('toolbar')) {
            $(window, context).resize(function() {
              var toolbarHeight = $('div#toolbar').height();
              var zoneuserHeight = $('div#toolbar').height() + $('div#zone-user').height();
              $('.zone-user-wrapper').css('top', toolbarHeight + 'px');
              $('.zone-menu-super-wrapper').css('top', zoneuserHeight + 'px');
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Also, make sure that your `.zone-menu-super-wrapper` has `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` otherwise the `top: zoneuserHeight` won't work.

Example: [Does Not Work](http://jsfiddle.net/3161gqjm/)
Example: [Works](http://jsfiddle.net/3161gqjm/1/)

**PS:**

perhaps this line

```
var zoneuserHeight = $('div#toolbar').height() + $('div#zone-user').height();
```

needs to be

```
var zoneuserHeight = $('div#toolbar').height() + $('div#zone-user-wrapper').height();
```

Comment: Nearly there - I added in the code you recommended. It does not work without changing the zone-menu-super `{position: relative}`, as you stated. However, that negates my ability to keep this zone as sticky. I need both "zone-user" and "zone-menu-super" to be sticky. Out of the box from Commerce Kickstart, "zone-user" is sticky, but I don't see the position call out in the global.css for that zone. In order to make my new zone sticky, I added in `position: fixed;`, but ran into this issue with the admin menu. What am I missing here?  PS `absolute` does not work :)

Comment: "I added in position: fixed; but ran into this issue with the admin menu". so you made `.zone-menu-super { position: fixed; }` so whats the issue with admin menu?

Comment: When in the admin view, the new "zone-menu-super" disappears. As the page loads, I see it build, but then it disappears behind the admin menu. However, the Commerce-created "zone-user" does not behave this way.